# Can two different programs be run on the same holodeck/holosuite?

Tags: star-trek, holodeck

For example, could Captain Picard command the computer to use half of Holodeck 2 for his Dixon Hill program, so that Worf can use the other half to fight monsters?

Comment: The holodecks (as seen when they're deactivated) aren't that big. It's already a bit of a handwave how they don't walk into the walls all the time; now imagine subdividing that space...

Comment: Since holodecks can be programmed, in principle they could write a program where two different stories run in each half, however probably that would be quite complicated. Splitting the time one can use the holodecks is much simpler I guess.

Comment: @Cadence They wouldn't be much smaller than Quark's holosuites.

Comment: If this were possible, why would they need 16 holodecks?

Comment: @Cadence a floor with a treadmill effect is hardly a handwave.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's possible. Not only two programs, maybe even more. Nevertheless, as Cadence stated, they aren't that big, so that it could be possible to accidentally touch or hit another person.

**But**: If you watch the episodes with long running programs (This village in Voyager, Vic Fontaine in DS etc) the same holodeck is used for dozens of crewmen. They are not always in the same room or place within the program. This has to be handled by the computer.

If you image the size of Vic Fontaine's club, it's not even close to the size of the holodock in Quark's. So if some crewman is at the bar and another one near the stage, it must be virtualized by the holodeck.

The holodeck program has also to care about noise and sounds. The one at the stage hears music much louder than the one at the bar. Also, they should not hear the dialogs from each other.

So, I think eventually it is possible in theory, but the computer of the holodeck must also have the needs for that (running two or more programs simultaneously could be a challenging task)

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I thought when reading the question,  the holo-deck is running 2 programs at once whenever there is multiple people in it as everyone will see and hear different things. If it does it all the time then it shouldn't be hard to write a program with 2 different environments

Answer (score 1):

@christoph's answer is perfectly good.

Consider also that we know it's possible to run a holodeck simulation INSIDE a holodeck simulation. Like when Picard realized that he was inside a recreation of the Enterprise that Moriarty created. (TNG: Ship in a Bottle). The "exit" from 221B Baker Street to the Enterprise hallway was just a door.

So, to answer your question, yes. You just have an "exit" from Dix's office to some jungle full of monsters. Then "close" the "exit." Easy as pie.